# Building Ionic v6 cordova android angular13 app returns ERROR "An unhandled exception occurred: Project target does not exist."

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to create an ionic v6 app using cordova and angular13 latest versions, I am getting this error when running `ionic cordova build android`

[image]

More details about issue reproduction here in the below bug report:
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/24940

Code Reproduction URL
https://github.com/MoAsmar/temp-ionic6

Answer (score 0):

Ionic CLI v6.19.0 has been released with this fix:

```
npm install -g @ionic/cli@latest
```

bug report on GitHub:
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/24940#issuecomment-1068016921

[image]